# How to check the current background color wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I check the current color of a button here is the code so far

```
private void firstClick(object changer, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button x = (changer as Button);

            if (x backgroundcolor is blue)
            {

                x.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue);
                click++;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WPF Color structure has an [equality operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.color.op_equality?view=netframework-4.7.2), so you can simply write this:

```
if (((SolidColorBrush)x.Background).Color == Colors.Blue)
{ 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        public bool Equals(SolidColorBrush brush1, SolidColorBrush brush2) {
        return brush1.Opacity == brush2.Opacity &&
            brush1.Color.A == brush2.Color.A &&
            brush1.Color.R == brush2.Color.R &&
            brush1.Color.B == brush2.Color.B &&
            brush1.Color.G == brush2.Color.G;
    }
```

To get the color:

```
Color color1 = (Color)brush1.GetValue(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty);
```

Usage:

```
Button x = (changer as Button);
Brush blue = Brushes.Blue;
if (Equals(x.BackgroundColor,blue)) {
    x.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue);
    click++;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to have touble with the other answer (its cortrect by the way) lets make it simple 
use this:

```
        var yourColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        if ((x.Background as SolidColorBrush).Color.A == yourColor.A &&
            (x.Background as SolidColorBrush).Color.R == yourColor.R &&
            (x.Background as SolidColorBrush).Color.G == yourColor.G &&
            (x.Background as SolidColorBrush).Color.B == yourColor.B)
        {
            //do something nice here
        }
```